# Android TextView underline works not

Tags: android, textview, underline

I want to do a simple thing - to underline a text in TextView. The string is placed in strings.xml (because of translations):

```
<string name="mytext"><u>UnderlineText</u></string>
```

And then I put the text programmatically:

```
 TextView txt1 = findViewById(R.id.autor);
 txt1.setText(resources.getString(R.string.mytext));
```

However, for some reason, the `<u>` in strings file is ignored and my text is not underlined.

I also tried:

```
 txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.mytext)));
```

still nothing. The text is shown normally, not underlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

> `<string name="mytext"><![CDATA[<u>UnderlineText</u>]]> </string>`

Comment: ah, I don't believe I didn't try this before. Working fine. Thank you.!

Answer (score 3):

Try using getText() instead of getString().

```
txt1.setText(resources.getText(R.string.mytext));
```

This returns the localized String including the style.

Comment: In your way, we don't need to use Html.fromHtml or SpannableString... Thanks!!!